# Proving that the indiscrete topology is a valid topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

The proof is somewhat obvious, but I want to make sure that the steps are fully rigorous. Here is my attempt.

> Now, let $\mathcal{T}_i = \{\emptyset, X\}$. By definition, $\emptyset, X \in \mathcal{T}_i$. If $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a collection of elements of $\mathcal{T}_i$, the union over $I$ can be reduced to a union over $1$ or $2$ distinct elements; a union over $1$ element is necessarily in $\mathcal{T}_i$, so it suffices to consider only pairwise unions. We have
> \begin{align*}
> & \emptyset \cup \emptyset = \emptyset \hspace{20mm} \emptyset \cup X = X \cup \emptyset = X  \hspace{20mm} X \cup X = X,
> \end{align*}
> as required. Finally, we check finite intersections. Let $U_1, \ldots, U_n \in \mathcal{T}_i$. As intersection is commutative and associative and $A \cap A = A$ for every $A \in \mathcal{T}_i$, any intersection over $n$ elements can be reduced to an intersection over $1$ over $2$ distinct elements. Therefore, again, it suffices to consider only pairwise intersections. We have
> \begin{align*}
> \emptyset \cap \emptyset = \emptyset \hspace{20mm} \emptyset \cap X = X \cap \emptyset = \emptyset \hspace{20mm} X \cap X = \emptyset,
> \end{align*}
> as required.

How does this look? Is the logic of "removing duplicates" sufficiently rigorous?

Comment: It looks good; you can avoid the "remove duplicates" by noting that in an arbitrary union, if any of the sets is $X$ then you get $X$, and otherwise they are all empty and you get the empty set; and dually, in the intersection, if any of the sets is empty you get the empty set, and if none are then they are all $X$ and you get $X$.